# server.transfer in express node js

Tags: c#, node.js, express

I would like to transfer request one server to another server. Like server.transfer in C#. I know we can go for response.redirect  or response.writeHead methods in nodejs but these have a client side (browser) interaction.

In my case, the user should not see where I am redirecting as it should server to server call.

As of now, I have achieved by [unirest](http://unirest.io/nodejs.html).

```
app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
   unirest.get("www.example.com/userdetails").end(function (res) {
      response.send(res.body)
   });
});
```

But am expecting same in express. suggestions welcome.

Comment: Am I correct in saying you simply want two URLs to hit the same endpoint on the server?

Comment: In other word. i want redirection option in server side. which need to be, when the server receive some api request its need to redirect to some other server api.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that inside express with [http.request](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) method, but you can also use higher level packages, like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I expect like c# server.transfer method in express. is there any method its kind of server.transfer in express?

Comment: I don't know about the details of server.transfer, but as far as your question is concerned, your goal is to make http calls inside your express app which is possible by the packages mentionned above.

Comment: Not. I want to redirect API calls without HTTP. I want do like response.redirect in single line express. while using response.redirect method client can see where am redirecting but i don't want to show them

Answer (score 0):

I created an express module to add `req.transfer(path, preserveData)` to all routes. This allows you to internally transfer requests without sending a redirect to the client:

```js
var express = require('express');
var requestTransfer = require('express-request-transfer');

var app = express();
app.use(requestTransfer); // adds req.transfer method to all routes

// route 1
app.get('/api/time', function(req, res){
    res.send(new Date());
});

// route 2
app.post('/', function(req, res){

    // transfer without form/query data
    req.transfer('/api/time');

    // transfer with incoming form/query data
    // req.transfer('/api/time', true);
});
```

It functions the same as [Server.Transfer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525800(v%3Dvs.90)) from C#. Source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/john-doherty/express-request-transfer)

Comment: Which will help me to redirect in same server/app. i want to redirect to another server/app api.

Comment: In that case you should use a res.redirect